# Cancel local changes when "The content on disk is newer. Please compare..."

Tags: visual-studio-code

I did the following to reset my changes

```
git checkout .
```

Unfortunately I made some unsaved changes on a file and I want to cancel these changes.

I did not find the option `Reopen from disk` and my current solution is:

1. Close the file (Ctrl+F4)
2. Press `Don't Save` (Tab, Enter)
3. Reopen the file (Ctrl+P, Navigate and select the file, Enter)

Is there a better way?

What I need is the:

```
:e!
```

from Vim...